# Are these requests to www.mydomain.com/css/about:blank a broken link or something else?

Tags: asp.net, exception

We recently implemented a new error page on our website which sends emails to the webmaster containing the most recent server exception. We are running a ASP.NET 4 application, and last night we got many emails that were all the same error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

These errors we have seen before, but the odd thing is the path that is being requested. It is always the path:

> http://www.mydomain.com/css/about:blank

I have scoured the different pages and can find no anchor tag that appears to point to any link like this. Is this an issue with our application or something else? In other words, do we need to fix anything or just ignore these?

Also, this path was requested consistently, seemingly by the same users, and often was requested from multiple pages they visited. User-agents ranged from Firefox to IE7 and 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done anything like this in your css: background-image:url(about:blank);

This shouldn't generate a http request however so I suspect you might have maybe a ./about:blank in there instead.

Comment: Oh my, I can't believe I didn't notice that, I assumed I had not placed anything like that into the css file but it appears I have, is there any way to stop these requests?

Comment: well, about:blank shoudln't really make an http request so if you post the css that has about:blank in it I can help further. As I said you have probably included a ./ or something like that in the url.

Comment: `a.orangeLink
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:161px;
    height:34px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    z-index:17;
    background-image:url(about:blank);
}`

Comment: That is the only place I know of that uses that. We needed it to allow internet explorer to click an empty a tag I guess.

Comment: This http://haslayout.net/css/No-Transparency-Click-Bug appears to suggest that if you set the url to the css file itself you should side step the issue (this won't result in an extra get request as the file will be cached).